# ValueError: too many values to unpack, error when reading text files

Tags: python

I am trying to open some text files read them and get all characters from a-z from inside those files and do some more processing with these characters.

but i am getting the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

here is the start of my script and its on the commented line of this code block that i get the error

```
for line in sys.stdin:

    if ":" in line:

        filename, line = line.strip().split(':') # this line gives error
```

its something to do with split it seems. The reason i do it this way is because i want to also extract the filename and i read somewhere else before that when stdin reads files, its of the format

`filename.txt: Start of the first line inside the text file`

also i have tried this on a single text file and it worked but now that i try the full batch i get this

i call it from console like this

`grep -r '' susp-text | ./mapper.py | sort | ./suspicious_reducer.py`

the error is on the first script `mapper.py`

bigger picture of script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

# regular expressions

pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]*",
                 re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)

a_to_f_pattern = re.compile("[a-fA-F]", re.IGNORECASE)
g_to_l_pattern = re.compile("[g-lG-L]", re.IGNORECASE)
m_to_r_pattern = re.compile("[m-rM-R]", re.IGNORECASE)
s_to_z_pattern = re.compile("[s-zS-Z]", re.IGNORECASE)

# Read pairs as lines of input from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
    if ":" in line:

        filename, line = line.strip().split(':')
        filename = filename.replace("source_text/", "")
        filename = filename.replace("suspicious_text/", "")

        # loop through every word that matches the pattern
        for word in pattern.findall(line):
            while i < len(word):
```

extract from first text file that is read

```
 Even without the
nets, caught she will be, from sheer fatigue, (15) owing to the depth of the snow, which balls
itself under her shaggy feet and clings to her, a sheer dead weight.

 (11) Al. "to envelop the victims in the nets."

 (12) Lit. "whatever the creature is in contact with inside."

 (13) Cf. Aesch. "Prom." 87, {Poto tropo tesd' ekkulisthesei tukhes}.

 (14) Or, "if the creature is not first suffocated in the snow itself."

 (15) See Pollux, v. 50. "She must presently be tired out in the heavy
    snow, which balls itself like a fatal clog clinging to the under
    part of her hairy feet."
```

Comment: What exactly is your "second line"? What is the input? What is the exact state of variables when the unexpected behaviour happens?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the second line, it was actually the third line, i commented it to be more clear, i also put the input there of a text file, as for the state of variables this happens before anything gets printed out that i do after the above code block so it seems that it stops the script there

Comment: You should rather reduce your problem yourself. Is it reading a line that fails? Is it rather handling a line with a certain content? Concentrate on just that issue, extract a minimal example that demonstrates the unepected behaviour and post that here. The site rules explicitly demand this because it avoids questions that would be solved automatically if people tried to reduce and analyze their code carefully.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you might have a line with more than one ":" in it. In which case, `split` will return a list with more than two items, which is too many to put into two variables.

Try specifying the maximum split amount:

```
filename, line = line.strip().split(':', 1)
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `.partition` so you always get three results, and can test if it matched rather than raising exceptions (personal preference). e.g. `filename, sep, line = line.strip().partition(':')`, `if not sep: ... skip line ...`